# Respond to 'done' button in TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I want to respond to the user pressing the 'done' button on their keyboard when typing in a TextFormField.

Code so far:

```
            TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'ENTER YOUR TASK'
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: It automatically considers it as submit, if you still want to override you can use `onsubmit` param in TextFormField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [onFieldSubmitted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) or  [onEditingComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextField/onEditingComplete.html) property.

**onEditingComplete**

> - When a completion action is pressed, such as "done", "go", "send", or "search", the user's content is submitted to the controller and then focus is given up.
> - When a non-completion action is pressed, such as "next" or "previous", the user's content is submitted to the controller, but focus is not given up because developers may want to immediately move focus to another input widget within onSubmitted.

Example,

```
          TextFormField(
            onEditingComplete: (){
              //do your stuff   
              },
          )
```

**onFieldSubmitted**

> onSubmitted is called when the user indicates that they are done editing the text in the field.

Example,

```
          TextFormField(
            onFieldSubmitted: (val){
              // process
            },
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = new TextEditingController();


TextFormField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        autofocus: true,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        onEditingComplete: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          print(_textEditingController.text);
       //TODO your Response code for user
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'ENTER YOUR TASK'),
      ),
```